# Push notification not recieved on first launch

Tags: ios, sinch

I am using the sinch SDK on a project. The push notification with type voip are not recieved on the first launchs, but recieved after many kill/open application.
this is the initialisation of the client

```
func initSinchClient(userIdentifier : String!) -> SINClient! {


    if let _ = self.sinchClient{
        self.sinchClient?.unregisterPushNotificationDeviceToken()
        self.sinchClient?.stopListeningOnActiveConnection()
        self.sinchClient?.terminate()
    }

    self.sinchClient = Sinch.client(withApplicationKey: SinchConstants.SinchAppKey, applicationSecret: SinchConstants.SinchApplicationSecret, environmentHost: SinchConstants.SinchEnvironmentHost, userId: userIdentifier)
    self.sinchClient!.delegate = self
    self.sinchClient!.call().delegate = self

    self.sinchClient!.setSupportActiveConnectionInBackground(true)
    self.sinchClient!.setSupportPushNotifications(true)
    self.sinchClient!.setSupportCalling(true)
    self.sinchClient?.enableManagedPushNotifications()
    self.sinchClient!.start()
    self.sinchClient!.startListeningOnActiveConnection()

    if let pushTokenData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "PushNotificationToken"){
        self.sinchClient!.registerPushNotificationData((pushTokenData as! NSData) as Data!)
    }
    return sinchClient
}
```

This is when i set the token

```
func pushRegistry(registry: PKPushRegistry!, didUpdatePushCredentials credentials: PKPushCredentials!, forType type: String!) {
    // Register VoIP push token (a property of PKPushCredentials) with server

    if let sinchCLient = SinchManager.sharedInstance.sinchClient{
        if let _ = SessionManager.sharedInstance.user {
            sinchCLient.registerPushNotificationData(credentials.token)

        }

    }

}
```

how can i resolve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i solved the problem by moving the registration of VOIP push

```
let mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue()
    // Create a push registry object
    let voipRegistry: PKPushRegistry = PKPushRegistry(queue: mainQueue)
    // Set the registry's delegate to self
    voipRegistry.delegate = self
    // Set the push type to VoIP
    voipRegistry.desiredPushTypes = [PKPushTypeVoIP]
```

before initializing the push object instantiation and configuration

```
 self.push = Sinch.managedPushWithAPSEnvironment(.Production)
    self.push!.delegate = self
    self.push!.setDesiredPushType(SINPushTypeVoIP)
    self.push!.registerUserNotificationSettings()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want push right away dont start aactive connection, active connection sets up a socket and as long the app is alive you will get the the incoming call right away instead.

May i ask why you are doing this in the init. you should not have to do that. If you have login log out functionality you should do that duriong log out, not init. and you should use terminateSuccesfully

```
 if let _ = self.sinchClient{
    self.sinchClient?.unregisterPushNotificationDeviceToken()
    self.sinchClient?.stopListeningOnActiveConnection()
    self.sinchClient?.terminate()
}
```

Comment: I modified the code like you recommend. The issue is not solved. The push notification is not received until i kill the application and reopen.